# Are there rules that tells the Bank of Japan what kind of stock purchases it can make?

Tags: japan, central-bank

> (Bloomberg) -- In most of the world, exchange-traded funds are simply
> tools that allow investors to track a certain set of stocks. In Japan,
> they’ve been saddled with everything from propping up the market and
> boosting inflation, to accelerating economic growth, improving
> corporate governance and even encouraging gender equality.
>
> Such wide-ranging goals have led the Japanese central bank to amass a
> whopping 80% of the country’s ETFs—equivalent to about 7% of its $6
> trillion stock market—in less than a decade. That’s far further than
> any other central bank in the world has gone in trying to prime its
> economy via equities purchases. The Bank of Japan has also outpaced
> peers with its $3.7 trillion in net bond purchases.

https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/a-430-billion-habit-got-japan-s-central-bank-hooked-on-etfs-1.1749440

Are there rules that tells the Bank of Japan what kind of stock purchases it can make? From the article, it seems like the BOJ can't buy stocks outright, but has to do it through ETFs, but is it really the cases, what are some of the rules the BOJ need to follow when making direct or indirect stock purchases through ETFs?

Comment: First result on Google is a collection of the relevant policy documents in English:  https://www.boj.or.jp/en/mopo/measures/mkt_ope/ope_t/index.htm

Comment: This article is old but relevant: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w25525/revisions/w25525.rev2.pdf

Comment: "Are there rules that tells the Bank of Japan what kind of stock purchases it can make?" The answer is yes. But, I presume the real question is what those rules say.